# R View(matrix) or View(dataframe) in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When using the command `View(matrix)` or `View(dataframe)` or by doubleclicking in Rstudio on the Data in the global environment, a screen shows up in which you can see your data. However, when scrolling down on that screen the column names dissappear. Is there a "freeze panes" option as in excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find `gvisTable` from package `googleVis` quite convenient when viewing data in RStudio.
"The gvisTable function reads a data.frame and creates text output referring to the Google Visualisation API, which can be included into a web page, or as a stand-alone page. The actual chart is rendered by the web browser."

`gvisTable` opens a [viewer pane in RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/viewer_pane) (where local web content can be viewed). The headers are always visible and there are several options that allow you to customize the view. You can sort by variables by clicking on their header.

A simple example:

```
library(googleVis)
gt <- gvisTable(iris)
plot(gt)

gt <- gvisTable(iris, options = list(page = 'enable', height = 200))
plot(gt)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It's unfortunately not really working for me. When I use the gvisTable command it just 'spams' my console, I tried tying it to getOption("viewer") as suggested in your link but that did not work either. Could you perhaps give me a more complete code? Here's the result of the plot function you suggested http://127.0.0.1:18832/custom/googleVis/Chart_TableID10bc30262ccb.html ... Does not look much like a matrix quite yet :(

Comment: @simon_icl Thanks for your comments. The code I posted works fine for me in with `R version 3.0.3`, `RStudio 0.98.484`, `googleVis_0.4.7` and I thought it should be self-contained. I have never used a 'more complete code' than this, and have not made any changes in RStudio to make it work. My code is basically just the two first examples in `?gvisTable` but with another data set.

Comment: Hi @Henrik, I have a more recent version of RStudi (0.98.501) but not sure if that's why. Do I have to install this Google Visualisation API as well or should that just work in the cloud?

Comment: When running `library(googleVis)`, I get the message "Note, the plot method of googleVis will by default use the RStudio Viewer pane to display its output". I haven't installed anything and, again, I have made no changes in RStudio. The example should be self-contained, so it strange that it doesn't work for you...